# Import an external table and adding footnote table

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have  created a table in csv format which I have converted into .tex format and I simply import that same table into latex.

```
\input{./tables/EMEA.tex}
```

Is it possible to add a footnote to my external table (a note just under the table to clarify )?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What did you try? Could you post a minimal full code?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.